# How to modify wireless ath5k driver?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm using my wireless card with `ath5k`. Everything works fine but I'd like to modify this driver.

I've downloaded its [source code](http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/) to have an overview of files structure.

Let's assume that I want to edit `base.c` file which is located (in `compat-wireless` package) in `ath5k` directory.

After typing:

```
find / -name base.c
```

I can't find it in Linux file system. Where should I look for these files?

Comment: The .c file is part of the source code, which is then compiled into binary, and binary is what you have on a working system. So, to modify a driver, you first edit the source code, then compile, then install it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download, extract and modify this: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13.2/backports-3.13.2-1.tar.xz

The file you are seeking exists there: *backports-3.13.2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/base.c*